# How to embed Python in MFC with embeddable package

Tags: python, c++, mfc

I am developing a 32-bit desktop application(MFC) on a 64-bit computer.

Since this application is intended for use by others who most likely do not have the 32-bit version of Python installed,so I downloaded the Windows embeddable package (32-bit) hoping to resolve the issue.

However, after downloading it, I couldn't find the python.h

In this case, how can I call functions like Py_Initialize() / PyRun_SimpleString(), etc.?
Or does the embeddable package only allow calling python.exe with system()/ShellExecute()?

I have installed python 32bit version, and I successfully executed my py script.
I just want to do the same things with embeddable package.

Answer (score 2):

Use can follow this steps to resolve your problem.

Install the Python development source files for the version you downloaded (32-bit).
These files typically include headers like python.h.

In Visual Studio, configure the project settings to include the path to the Python include directory where python.h is located.

Link your project with the appropriate Python library (e.g., python38.lib).

You can now use Python embedding functions like Py_Initialize() and PyRun_SimpleString() in your MFC application.

Comment: but other people can't use this way, they don't have 32bit python.

Comment: See the documentation for [The embeddable package](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) The embedded distribution is a ZIP, and python3.dll, python37.dll, python.exe and pythonw.exe are all provided. Quoting the doc: "extracting the embedded distribution to a subdirectory of the application installation is sufficient to provide a loadable Python interpreter."